# How to create an outline polygon (footprint) from raster data with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, polygon, footprint

How can I create a polygon, containing the actual outlines (aka footprint) of a raster file with PostGIS?

I just need the outlines of the data containing parts of the raster.

ST_PixelAsPolygon creates a complex polygons - but I just need the footprint.

There is a similar question here [Creating shapefile showing footprints of Rasters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/how-do-i-create-a-shapefile-showing-footprints-of-rasters), but the answers do not cover PostGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ST_Envelope](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/RT_ST_Envelope.html) function:

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(rast)
  FROM raster_table;
```

This will return a rectangular bounding box for your raster(s). PostGIS describes what this function returns as:

> Returns the polygon representation of the extent of the raster.

Comment: This gives me just a rectangular envelope (bounding box). I'm looking for a polygon which describes the data area of the raster. With satellite pictures the resulting polygon will be a trapezoidal shape in most cases.

Comment: The shape can be projection-dependent. Why don't you try ST_PixelAsPolygon followed by [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_ConvexHull.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at ST_DumpAsPolygons. It will draw the polygons around your raster shapes.