# Obtain the footprint of a large raster in PostGIS

Tags: raster, postgis, polygon, postgresql

I need to get the footprint (not the **extent**) 10GB raster in PostGIS similar to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39171/how-to-create-an-outline-polygon-footprint-from-raster-data-with-postgis) (but it's a very old question without any proper answer). So far the best approach I have come up with is

```
WRITE TABLE myschema.mypolygon AS 
SELECT
    ST_DumpAsPolygons(ST_Reclass(rast,
    '(0-100):1',
    '16BUI', -9999))
FROM
    myschema.myraster;
```

This basically changes all the raster values to 1 (I know the range is well within 0-100) and then passes this raster over to `ST_DumpAsPolygons` which will create polygons based on raster values.

I am wondering if there is a faster and more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know if there is a faster way to do this, because that's usually how I do it and it's not really the bottleneck part usually. But here is a few idea that maybe can help you:

- Try to prefilter using `ST_SummaryStats` to only do the reclass and dump for tiles that are not full of data (the count is the number of values different of `nodata`, so if you compare to the size of the tile you can know the number of `nodata`). For the tiles that are full, you can use `ST_Envelope` of your tile that is maybe a bit faster. Once you got the envelopes and the polygons dumps, you can union it to have your final result.
- If your `nodata` is on the outside, maybe you can use `ST_MinConvexHull`. If not, maybe it's at least on the outside of your tiles so you can apply that tile by tile then union the result.
- Parallelize the work on your tiles. I usually call postgres requests from a python script that launch parallel queries when postgres cannot parallelize the work itself. In this kind of cases, each parallel worker would process only tiles modulo a number (`WHERE MOD(rid, nb_core) == num_worker`). You insert your result polys into a table that you can later union.