# extracting the outline of raster imagery using GDAL

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, gdal

Salams I want some help regarding developing a method using GDAL to extract and represent the footprint of any raster file (or group of raster data) in a vector format... any ideas please ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the gdaltindex command at the command line for this. Here is an example.

gdaltindex output.shp folder/*.tif

You could also use a QGIS plugin for this as inidicated in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/how-do-i-create-a-shapefile-showing-footprints-of-rasters).