# How to create a boundary polygon around raster extent (.tif) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, polygonize, boundaries

I would like to create a polygon around the raster (.tif) extent so I can calculate for instance the area in m2 within the polygon.

When I try to Polygonize or Clip raster by extend (and delete the 0 value) the vector data comes out with a lot of holes inside, which will make area calculation inaccurate. See figure below for clarification.

Does someone knows a handy way to create a polygon around the data extent?

[image: actual polygon boundary versus intended polygon boundary]

Comment: Hi! Already answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/creating-shapefile-showing-footprints-of-rasters

Comment: @pan, thank you for the suggestion I will check it out!

Comment: Create a black/white raster with raster calculator and an appropriate expression (like `raster@1 > 0` or whatever fits your data), then it's much easier to polygonize the resulting raster.